# Searching array of directories if file exists

Tags: c, file, loops, search

I have an algorithm that looks at an array that contains multiple paths, and checks if a command (such as ls, wc, cat ... etc) exists in any of the directories listed in the array. If the file is found in one of the directories, returns the full directory path.

```
char *LookupPath(char **argv, char **dir)
{
    /* String Name To Be Returned */
    char *result;
    char path_name[MAX_PATH_LEN] = {0};
    int i;

    /* Check To See If File Name Is Already An Absolute Path Name */
    if(*argv[0] == '/') {

    }

    /* Look In Path Directories */
    for(i = 0; dir[i] != NULL; i++) {
        strncat(path_name, dir[i], sizeof(path_name));
        strncat(path_name, "/", sizeof(path_name));
        strncat(path_name, argv[0], sizeof(path_name));
        printf("pathname: %s\n", path_name);
        result = path_name;
        if(access(result, F_OK) == 0) {
            printf("SUCCESS!\n");
            printf("result: %s\n", result);
            return result;
        }
        path_name[0] = '\0';
    }

    /* File Name Not Found In Any Path Variable */
    return NULL;
}
```

New problem: When using a command such as ls -l or anything else, the result works beautifully as shown in the below result code.

```
pathname: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/ls
pathname: /usr/local/sbin/ls
pathname: /usr/local/bin/ls
pathname: /usr/sbin/ls
pathname: /usr/bin/ls
pathname: /sbin/ls
pathname: /bin/ls
SUCCESS!
result: /bin/ls
```

However, now when I use just a simple command such as 'ls' on it's on...the result is false...because for some reason, a new line character is added to ls...? It appears:

```
pathname: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/ls

pathname: /usr/local/sbin/ls

pathname: /usr/local/bin/ls

pathname: /usr/sbin/ls

pathname: /usr/bin/ls

pathname: /sbin/ls

pathname: /bin/ls

pathname: /usr/games/ls

pathname: /usr/local/games/ls

ls
: Command Not Found!
```

I don't know why. Is there any way to cut it down to just 'ls'. I don't know why a new line character is being added to argv[0] when it's just a simple ls command. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call it in a loop because you're modifying the dir strings: strcat() appends the source string to the destination by modifying it (and you use the dir strings as destination). Additionally, since you don't make any provisions for the extended string lengths, you're writing past the end of the string memory and corrupt other memory.

You need to create a char array of sufficient length as a local variable and construct the pathname to test in there. Better use snprintf() instead of strcat() and make sure the created path fit into your string. Also, since you can't return a local string, in the success case you need to malloc() a new string of the result length and copy the result in there.

As for checking it's not already absolute, check if the first letter of the name is '/'. Which you already do, it seems.

Comment: You're saying I'm using dir as a destination but last I checked, strcat is (dest, src)...and I don't see me using it as a dest. What would be the proper code then? :S

Comment: You do "result = dir[i];" then "strcat(result, "/");" so result is the same as dir[i]. You're modifying the string dir[i] points to.

Comment: Okay so I have the array now char path_name[MAX_SIZE]; How would I go about constructing it in it? :S Say...using snprintf... where I want to use dir[i]/argv[0]...

Comment: snprintf() works exactly like printf(), except it prints into a string, so a format of "%s/%s" with the given strings should do. Check that the return value (number of printed characters) is not greater than MAX_SIZE, otherwise the target string was truncated. Also, you should really read up on how strings work in C (in particular that C does not know strings, just arrays) otherwise you will continue to have lots of problems (and serious bugs even if it appears to work) like the one in your original question.

Comment: Hey, I've fixed the main problem...but please re-read the problem. I have a new problem now. I've added the fixed code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there are libraries that will do this for you, but your real problem is that you are appending to the paths in dir every time through the loop.

result is ptr

and these lines actually append /argv[0] to each element in the path every time 
you enter the loop

```
    result = dir[i];
    strcat(result, "/");
    strcat(result, argv[0]);
```

You need to create a temporary char buffer and use either multiple strcats or sprintf to fill the contents. FWIW, you should really get in the habit of using strncat or similar string functions with length parameters. Code like this is the start of many security problems. Something like this

```
     char result[PATH_MAX]; 
     strncpy(dir[i],result,length(dir[i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, `strcat` looks to be the problem here. Assuming that `char **dir` is a standard array of strings, you're probably running off the end when you `strcat` onto it, and that's bad. [As I've said myself](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/25248641):

> **No!** No! Not `strcat`! `strcat` dispenses buffer overruns like the Sun dispenses sunlight! ...seriously, ***don't***.

You'll need to allocate some sort of buffer within the loop; say,

```
char buf[BUFSIZE] = {0};
result = buf;
```

where `BUFSIZE` is `#define`d as big enough (my wild estimate: try 300).

Then try the following:

```
strlcpy(buf, dir[i], BUFSIZE);
strlcat(buf, "/", BUFSIZE);
strlcat(buf, argv[0], BUFSIZE);
```

**WARNING**: I can't test this right now; I only *think* it works. Should go okay, though.

[Information on `strlcpy` and `strlcat`](http://www.gratisoft.us/todd/papers/strlcpy.html)